# zeppelin take all the resources of CPU when there are not job in running

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I install zeppelin by binary package with all interpreters, the version is 0.7.3. After I run some spark job and when all the job is finish, I found that zeppelin is still running and take all the resources of CPU, but there is not spark job run. Is there anyone know what happen or how to debug this?

Comment: Zeppelin holds onto the Spark driver context and also caches all query results in memory

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: You should restart your zeppelin in some interval sutiable to you to release the memory it holds.

Comment: It don't take much memory, it just take all resources of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try following:

1. remove all the interpreters except for spark which you are interested in for your notebook
2. open zeppelin spark UI (by going to spark interpreter settings and opening from there) and check the status of job to be sure that no other job is running.

Comment: I have remove all the interpreters except for spark, and confirm that there is not job run in the spark UI. It doesn't work.